# Why changes to a private variable is also done to a public one?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a public variable `Public AssetFamilyCollection As New Collection` which is a collection of the classe `AssetFamily` I've created.

Within a sub, I create an `AssetFamily` instance with `Dim familyChosen As AssetFamily`.
Then when I've identified the `AssetFamily` I want in the collection I do `Set familyChosen = AssetFamilyCollection(i)`

At some point, I make changes on `familyChosen` property and I noticed that those changes have also been done to `AssetFamilyCollection(i)`

I thought `familyChosen` was a private variable, a copy from `AssetFamilyCollection(i)`  and only exists inside the sub. Apparently not.

Why the public and private variable are impacted by the changes and not the private one in the sub ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it doesn't work like that.

The variable familyChosen is actually a reference to the same object as the array element is referring.

So you can modify that object either through that reference or through the array element.

Answer (score 3):

- This is the problem about the **Basic Type** and the **Object Type**.

  You may need to know the diffenerce between the **Deep Copy** and
  **Shallow Copy**.

---

- When the code "`Dim familyChosen As AssetFamily`" executed, a new
  “AssetFamily” was created.

  But, when "`Set familyChosen = AssetFamilyCollection(i)`" executed,
  nothing was created, you just made the familyChosen pointed to the
  “AssetFamily” that already existed.

---

- So, if you want a "copy" but not a "pointer", you can write a
  function in the class “AssetFamily”, such as “Clone”, to create a new
  "AssetFamily" and make it the same as the old one.

  Then, you can write something like this:

  `Set familyChosen = AssetFamilyCollection(i).Clone()`

Answer (score 2):

It's becuase of

```
Set familyChosen = AssetFamilyCollection(i)
```

'familyChosen' is now a reference to 'AssetFamilyCollection(i)'

Any changes to one instance will update the other as they are both referencing the same object.

Comment: Formally it's a reference to the same object as that referred to by the array element.